# MPMoviePlayerViewController is not working in ios 10.2

Tags: ios, iphone, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller, avkit

When i use below code on ios 10.2,

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *c = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
   [self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:c];
    [c.moviePlayer play];
```

But when I execute this code  this have stoped automatically on

> **MPMoviePlayerViewController *c = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

Please help.
Is any changes in info.plist?

Comment: I also have used the belwo code

Comment: AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    
    AVPlayer* player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
    player.volume = 5.0;
    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    layer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;

Comment: UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    //view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [player play];

Comment: But this is not playing videos